# Add Custom Tab in Short description Magento 2(PDP)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4, magento2.3.4, magento2.4.2-p1

I want to add a custom tab in a short description on PDP. Does anyone have any idea on how to maintain it?
I want it something to look like this -
[image]

[image]
Thanks,
Rashi

Comment: You need to do the customization for this one by creating separate attribute and show that text as tab into short descriptions.

Comment: Any steps you can recommend with example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answering my query but I got one simple solution for the same with Magento basics only.

Edit Product attribute i.e. short_desription & changes its Catalog Input Type for Store Owner value to Pagebuilder.

Then you have the authority to create as many tabs/or any other via page builder in the short description as well.

Thanks,
Rashi

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link out -

"https://www.cloudways.com/blog/custom-magento-2-tab/" , where you will get to create a product attribute that will render as a tab in the PDP , hope you got what you want , please do comment and vote if it were helpful. Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Thanks. but the solution that I provided above was with Magento default functionality & is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute first, then, add `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test.tab" template="Vendor_Module::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Then Create **custom_tab.phtml** and make a call to your product attribute here

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$product->getData('ATTRIBUTE_CODE');
?>
```

**if you are adding multiple tabs then make sure to add them in sort order**

Comment: Thanks for answering Pramod. But this didn't solve my query. This is for custom tab but my requirement was to add in short description

Comment: you can modify products view by copying it from magento core module and then just call your phtml in whatever container you want to call it, and rest will be same, suppose above layout adds it to product.info.details but if you want to add somewhere else then you just need to find out that reference block/container and just make a call to your block